# is it possible to add a filter to highcharts?

Tags: filter, highcharts

I was wondering if there is a feature existing in highcharts to filter the data on the chart? 
For example I have a bar chart and I want to implement a filter that will filter values on the chart (may be show charts with y axis value greater than a threshold or something of that sort)

Can anybody point me to the correct resource?

Comment: Well, you can set zoom level. You can also process your data on click of some button to do what you need. Kind of a vague question. Do you have an example?

Comment: I want to remove data from series on a button click

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your own buttons and call [setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes) In case hwen you need to modify data dynamically, you can use [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) / [addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries) / [remove()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, what do you mean by ´prepare your own buttons´?

Comment: Add HTML buttons or by renderer: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Renderer.button